# Ticks not working on two axes for ListLinePlot3D

Tags: plotting

Let's say I have a plot such that

```
ListLinePlot3D[
  {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 5}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.9, 1.1}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  Ticks -> {{0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.10}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
  AxesLabel->{"x","y","z"}
]
```

The resulting plot will have labels and ticks on the `x` axis, but the remaining axes with larger ranges will be blank. Further, the `x` label isn't near the axis. Why exactly is this? I have always been able to specify ticks before with any other plotting function in Mathematica.

[image: 3D plot with ticks only on x axis]

Comment: Looking at your ranges, your PlotRange and AxesOrigin directives may not make sense together. If you remove either one, then everything works fine. I would guess that, since {0, 0, 0} is well out of the plot range, weird things happen when you ask the axes to cross outside the plot range.

Answer (score 3):

As MarcoB said in the comments, the `AxesOrigin` was presenting a problem. Removing it fixed this exactly as looking for. Thanks!